# How set initial values to fields on form?

Tags: python, django

enter code hereI'm having some problems to solve a problem. I have a template, which allows the user to change some of their account settings. My goal is to initialize the form, with the user's default values, and he can keep or change them (by after submit form). However, until now the page does not render these values. I'm using a class based view, CreateView, for this purpose.

My code is listed below.

Here, is my CreateView.

```
class DetailUserInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin ,CreateView):
model = CustomUser.CustomUser
template_name = 'users/InfoUser.html'
login_url = settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL
context_object_name = 'user'
form_class = CustomUserChangeForm

def get_object(self):
    self.model = self.request.user
    return self.model

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(DetailUserInfoView, self).get_initial()
    initial = initial.copy()
    initial[config.USERNAME] = self.request.user.username
    initial[config.FIRST_NAME] = self.request.user.first_name
    initial[config.LAST_NAME] = self.request.user.last_name
    return initial

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = {'initial': self.get_initial()}
    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): #GET OBJECT ACTS AFTER THAN GET_OBJECT --> EXAMPLE OF GET_CONTEXT_DATA, I DIDN'T NEED THIS
    context = super(DetailUserInfoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['username'] = self.request.user.username
    return context
```

Here the form.

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

```
class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
    model = CustomUser.CustomUser
    fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'userType')
```

And finally an extract of template.

```
    <div id="infoMayOverride">
        <form class="getOverridedValues" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="usernameData">
                <label>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</label> <!--MODEL ON CREATEUSERVIEW IS CUSTOMUSER, AND NOW I NEED TO USE THIS FIELDS AND INHERITED FIELDS FROM USER CLASS-->
                <input type="text" id="usernameInput" value="{{ form.username }}">
            </div>
            <div id="firstNameData">
                <label>{{ form.first_name.label_tag }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" value="{{ form.first_name }}">
            </div>
            <div id="lastNameData">
                <label>{{ form.last_name.label_tag }}</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" value="{{ form.last_name }}">
            </div>
            <div id="divBtnChangeProfile">
                <input type="submit" class="btnChangeProfile" value="Atualizar Profile">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me. I am new to the Django environment, and have tried many approaches, and I have not yet been able to solve this problem.

--------------------------- Update ------------------------------------

Now, i can get initial values. But to view them i need to write on input form: `form.username.initial`, and with this i can't after submit form to update user values.

Anyone knows how to solve this type of problem??

Comment: Please paste your code instead of showing screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this problem solved. I will make my solution available, since it can help other people.

I had to make some changes to the code I provided behind.

Below is the code of view.

```
class DetailUserInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = CustomUser.CustomUser
template_name = 'users/InfoUser.html'
login_url = settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL
context_object_name = 'user'
form_class = CustomUserChangeForm

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return self.request.user

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(DetailUserInfoView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    u = self.request.user
    kwargs['username_initial'] = u.username
    kwargs['fName_initial'] = u.first_name
    kwargs['lName_initial'] = u.last_name

    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): #GET OBJECT ACTS AFTER THAN GET_OBJECT --> EXAMPLE OF GET_CONTEXT_DATA, I DIDN'T NEED THIS
    context = super(DetailUserInfoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    context['form'] = form
    return context
```

My form (with init function, to set initial values on form, and is called by `def get_form_kwargs(self)`).

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username_initial = kwargs.pop('username_initial', None)
        fName_initial = kwargs.pop('fName_initial', None)
        lName_initial = kwargs.pop('lName_initial', None)
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].initial = username_initial
        self.fields['first_name'].initial = fName_initial
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = lName_initial

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser.CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

And finnaly, in template I replace the tag input with `{{ form.username }}`.

I hope it can help someone who has the same problem.